# Simultaneous identical requests = double in database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, locking, playframework-2.2

My controller handles a POST request, inserting a object in PostgreSQL. It works like this :

1. Check if the object does not exist in DB
2. Save the object in DB

But sometimes, 2 identical requests come too close and I guess the second one does not find the object of the first one so both are written in DB.

I am on heroku and I must take scalability into account also : the two requests can come on different dynos ( static variable wont work )

I did not find anything about database locking in Play

Any idea ?

Comment: Set a `primary key`?

Comment: Multiple dynos? But you do have one database, right?

Comment: If setting a primary or unique key won't suffice, can you further explain what "*Check if the object does not exist in DB*" entails?

Comment: The "Check if the object does not exist in DB" part really should be handled by constraints inside the database. Do you have any constraints?

Comment: One DB indeed. Best practice Play! is to have a UUID primary key. I do have one.  To check if row exists, I read in DB and check if other fields are same. But I guess the first row is not already saved when the second row comes.

Comment: If these "other fields" aren't allowed to be the same, why not enforce it with a unique key constraint?

Comment: Good point I will test that

Comment: I fact, the problem happens rarely and in production. Arent there any risk to add such constraint ?